# the set/p command in batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a batch script that hides folders, files, ect. But I can only get it to work when the file name has no spaces. I have listed the code I have so far below.

I need some help getting it to work with spaces. Keep in mind I am sort of new to batch scripting, but have a pretty good idea of what I am doing. Also, please explain what your solution is (if you have one).

```
>@echo off
title File hider
:start
cls
Echo Do You Want to Hide or Unhide a Folder?
echo.
echo.
set/p cho=Choice:
if %cho% equ Hide goto a
if %cho% equ hide goto a
if %cho% equ Unhide goto b
if %cho% equ unhide goto b
if %cho% neq Hide goto c
:c
cls
echo That Is An Invalid Choice
pause
goto start
:a
cls
echo Enter the name of the folder you want to hide:
echo.
echo.
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto file
if NOT EXIST %name% goto 99
:file
attrib +h +s +r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
exit
:b
cls
echo Enter The Name Of The Folder You Want To See:
echo.
echo.
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto bellow
if NOT EXIST %name% goto 98
:bellow
attrib -h -s -r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
goto question
:question
cls
echo Do you want to open this folder/file?
echo.
echo.
set/p yn=Answer[y:n]
if %yn% equ y goto 1
if %yn% equ n goto 2
if %yn% equ Y goto 1
if %yn% equ n goto 2
if %yn% neq y goto 3
:1
start %name%
exit
:2
exit
:3
cls
echo Invalid Choice
pause
goto question
exit
:99
cls
echo That file name does not exist
pause 
goto a
:98
cls
echo that file name does not exist 
pause
goto b
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Enclose your `%name%` variables in quotes `"%name%"` then it counts as one filename. And please fix your spelling :-)

Comment: A little off topic, but I believe you meant `ping localhost -n 5`, -5 isn't a real flag (-4 and -6 exist and force it to use ICMPv4 or ICMPv6 respectively, but -n is a flag that sets the amount of times to ping). You can also connect all those pings to a single ping with as many repetitions as you want, or even use `timeout /t num_secs_to_wait`.

Comment: why don't use `ping localhost -30 > nul` instead of 6 times `ping localhost -5 > nul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double quotes like this:

```
set/p "name=Folder Name: "
if EXIST "%name%" goto file
if NOT EXIST "%name%" goto 99
:file
attrib +h +s +r "%name%"
```

and the `/i` makes the test case insensitive.

```
if /i "%cho%" equ "Hide" goto a
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra help with the /i making text case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have `%var%` and `var` contains spaces, you need to use `"%var%"`. Enclosing the string in quotes means the space is not interpreted as a separator. And if you are using an `IF` statement, then the quotes must be balanced either side of the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is helpful, but this is what I use in my batch files when I ask if the user would like to run another batch file as well (I have an updater that unzips folders from a server, and another that copies over data files. So I use this at the end of each to ask if the user would like to run the other updater).

It also has a warning for invalid entries.

```
set /p entry=INSERT INSTRUCTION HERE, Type OPTION(S), then press the enter key:
IF /I NOT %entry%==N IF /I %entry%==Y GOTO M1
IF /I NOT %entry%==Y IF /I %entry%==N GOTO M2
IF /I NOT %entry%==N IF /I NOT %entry%==Y GOTO M3

:M1
echo This is where 'Y' directs to.
pause >nul
GOTO END

:M2
echo This is where 'N' directs to.
pause >nul
GOTO END

::The below option is used to revert back to the BEG and is meant for any invalid entries, thus preventing inccorrect entry. This can also prevent the code from continuing until a valid entry is made.

::For a bit of visual fun, it is made to flash red when an ivalid entry is made. To remove, just delete the lines above the GOTO

:M3
cls
^


echo Please try again...^



color ca
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 100 >nul
color 4a
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 500 >nul
color ca
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 500 >nul
color 4a
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 500 >nul
color 0a

GOTO BEG

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed a couple things wrong with the code you programmed, so I've made a better version for you!

Original Code:

```
 @echo off
title File hider
:start
cls
Echo Do You Want to Hide or Unhide a Folder?
echo.
echo.
set/p cho=Choice:
if %cho% equ Hide goto a
if %cho% equ hide goto a
if %cho% equ Unhide goto b
if %cho% equ unhide goto b
if %cho% neq Hide goto c
:c
cls
echo That Is An Invalid Choice
pause
goto start
:a
cls
echo Enter the name of the folder you want to hide:
echo.
echo.
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto file
if NOT EXIST %name% goto 99
:file
attrib +h +s +r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
exit
:b
cls
echo Enter The Name Of The Folder You Want To See:
echo.
echo.
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto bellow
if NOT EXIST %name% goto 98
:bellow
attrib -h -s -r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
goto question
:question
cls
echo Do you want to open this folder/file?
echo.
echo.
set/p yn=Answer[y:n]
if %yn% equ y goto 1
if %yn% equ n goto 2
if %yn% equ Y goto 1
if %yn% equ n goto 2
if %yn% neq y goto 3
:1
start %name%
exit
:2
exit
:3
cls
echo Invalid Choice
pause
goto question
exit
:99
cls
echo That file name does not exist
pause 
goto a
:98
cls
echo that file name does not exist 
pause
goto b
```

Modified version:

```
    @echo off
title File hider
:start
cls
Echo Do You Want to Hide or Unhide a Folder?
echo.
echo.
set/p cho=Choice:
if %cho% equ Hide goto :a
if %cho% equ hide goto :a
if %cho% equ Unhide goto :b
if %cho% equ unhide goto :b
else goto :c
:c
cls
echo That Is An Invalid Choice
pause
goto start
:a
cls
echo Enter the name of the folder you want to hide:
echo.
echo.
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto :file
if NOT EXIST %name% goto :99
:file
attrib +h +s +r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
exit
:b
cls
echo Enter The Name Of The Folder You Want To See:
echo[
echo[
set/p name=Folder Name:
if EXIST %name% goto :bellow
if NOT EXIST %name% goto :98
:bellow
attrib -h -s -r %name%
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
echo Job Completed
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
ping localhost -5 > nul
goto :question
:question
cls
echo Do you want to open this folder/file?
echo.
echo.
set/p yn=Answer[y:n]
if %yn% equ y goto 1
if %yn% equ n exit
if %yn% equ Y goto 1
if %yn% equ n exit
else goto :3
:1
start %name%


:3
cls
echo Invalid Choice
pause
goto :question

:99
cls
echo That file name does not exist
pause 
goto :a

:98
cls
echo that file name does not exist 
pause
goto :b
```

Hopefully that clears a couple things up for you, if there is any errors with the code (there was a lot of lines in this one XD) let me know below!